# bootstrap dynamic form field doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can only select only one radio button within 9 radio button.
**I need to select one radio button in one section.

think, I select the mobile radio button of the green plus button section. when I click on green plus button it create a new section with red minus button.
** In the new created red button section the mobile radio button will selected and all the radio button in this section will disabled.

Many time I tried it myself but I cant solve the problems.

I also put a fiddle. Please help me.

[see this `fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/fjLk5vse/3/)

Comment: You question description is very hard to understand. Like a raw mind stream dump. So what is it that you are really need to accomplish? Make possible to select only one radio button per section?

Comment: Sorry for my poor description. yes I need to select one radio button per section and in the red button section the radio buttons need to disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<div class="form-group multiple-form-group">...</div>` just use `<form class="form-group multiple-form-group">...</form>`.

Replace your `div` tag with `form` tag, so its separated.

Comment: Thanks Kamil. It's work. But I need to disabled all the radio button of red button section.

Comment: Ok, then use this code in your `addFormGroup` function - `$formGroup.find('input[type=radio]').attr('disabled','true');`. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjLk5vse/6/)

Comment: Thanks @kamil.It's work. But I want to select the radio button in red section which was selected in green section.

Comment: see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6h1L9j8/) after clicking on green button of "phone 1" section I need to focus the input with green button of "phone 2" section. is it possible? help me.

Comment: Please see my previous comment.

Comment: Something like this? --> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6h1L9j8/4/). Added `$formGroup.parent().next().find('input[type=text]').focus();` to your `addFormGroup` function

Comment: see this and help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822160/after-redirecting-page-using-jquery-can-i-fill-an-input-field-on-new-page