# After redirecting page using jQuery, can I fill an input field on new page?

Tags: jquery, redirect

I put a jQuery redirect code in a page. After loading the page it opens a link on a new tab. I want to fill an input field with "myid1234" on the new page which is opened on new tab.
Is this possible?

here is [`fiddle link`](http://jsfiddle.net/m6unye84/)

Comment: if you want to fill your input field on the new page you need to declare relevant scripts. Eg. `$('input').val('myid1234');`. But, if you want to send value to the server and get it in another page, you will need to use PHP or Ajax calls.

Comment: so how can I do it using ajax calls? @kamil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't! Even if you want to use a javascript injection like for example:

```
javascript:void(document.forms[1].sellerID.value='myid1234');
```

Simply, because you want to access a different URL. If the page you want to access does exist in the same root, it would be possible. Check this link [example](http://www.sanmarx2.freevar.com) to see a working example (Just remember to allow the pop-ups).

Although, you still have one chance to make it work. I'm gonna show you with this simple example: suppose you want to search something with google engine, you wanna do something like this:

```
<div>
  <form method="GET" action="http://www.google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <label for="search-id">Search</label>
    <input name="q" class="data_field" id="search-id" type="search" placeholder="Introduce your request" />
    <button type='submit'>OK</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/5na4krqn/) to see a working example.
In your case you should replace `www.google.com/search` by the url action of the site, which is `http://www.shopabcfr.com/store/brochures.php`.
Hope it's useful!